# Error using Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 For SQL Server

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I am getting this error:

```
'HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

When I try to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database from a python script using pyodbc that is being deployed on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

As the Error suggests, this is a Timeout issue which means that the python script / AWS Lambda is not able to connect to the SQL Server database.

To fix it:

**On the python script**, make sure that you have access to the Microsoft SQL Server database.

**On AWS**, check to make sure that the Lambda has access to the Microsoft SQL Server database. This is usually just ensuring that the Lambda is in a VPC that has access to that Microsoft SQL Server database.

*PS: The Microsoft SQL Server Database was not on AWS RDS, but I am pretty sure the same would apply.*